# Obtaining random element from container which doesn't have strict element order in constant time

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, random-access

I have a custom container that provides access to its elements via a unique ID (simple int64). This ID is not an index hoverer, so the users of the container shouldn't care about the order of elements inside.

I have implemented simplest possible forward iterator which provides `operator++` to be able to use the container with range-based for loops.

But now, I want to get random element from the container by generating random number and using `std::next`, all of this in constant time, so forward iterator is not sufficient since its `operator++` will be called N times introducing linear complexity. To achieve constant speed I have to provide `operator+=` which will make my forward iterator a kind of random access iterator (the container is capable of providing constant time access). Am i correct here? If so, it introduces a concept of *order* which isn't really applicable to my container.

So, I need constant time random access, but no strict order as in `vector`, for example. Where is the error in my logic?

Comment: @Slava edited the question

Comment: And does "random  access" mean that you get *any* element from the container, or one with a specific id?

Comment: @BoPersson any element, ID is irrelevant in this case

Comment: If you have provided `operator++` isn't there already an order to your container, even if it's meaningless in relation to the stored objects?

Comment: I am afraid http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator requires order (see `a<b` etc)

Comment: In that case I would probably write some `random_element()` function returning a reference (or iterator), and not bother changing the iterator implementation.

Comment: @patatahooliga unordered_map's iterator is a forward iterator and provides only operator++ , but an unordered_map isn't really ordered, right?

Comment: You could have an iterator with `operator+=` which is not a RandomAccessiterator per se, and meeting _your_ requirement of constant time access.

Comment: `std::unordered_map` have ordered iterators, and the ordering changes from time to time

Comment: Ok, I can see the logic behind order that is changing from time to time. Thank you all for the comments.

Comment: @ПавелМуратов My point is that if you are ok with the notion of an unordered container offering `operator++` then you should also be ok with offering `operator+=`. `unordered_map` doesn't offer `operator+=` because it would either be restricting on implementations or it would have no complexity guarantees. If you can offer a constant-time `operator+=` without compromising some more important aspect of your container, then it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @patatahooligan oh, now I see. Thank you much for the rationale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your strategy of modifying `container::iterator` to give you access to a "random" element is unidiomatic. Because you will always be picking a number between `0` and `container::size()`, and adding it to `container::begin()`, you need to hold onto the `container`, not just an iterator

What you should instead do is add a member `template< class Generator > container::reference container::random_element( Generator& g )`, delegating to [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) to pick the element, and leave `container::iterator` as a [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) (or potentially a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator)).